# Why Does This Java Function Crash?

Tags: java, algorithm, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a simple Java method, which is suppose to compute a list of prime divisors of a certain number.

```
public class Factors {



public static List<Integer> fac(List<Integer> factors, int number) {
    if(number < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number must be greater than one");
    }


    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        while (number%i == 0) {
            factors.add(i);
            number /= i;
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(fac(factors, 2147483647));

final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) );
}
}
```

This code works fine, except you feed Integer.MAX_VALUE into it; in that case giving:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Initially, I thought, that this is due to, that ArrayList initialization was inside a method, but after removing, the same error persists.
Moreover, this:

```
public static List<Long> facrec2(List<Long> list, long number) {
    if (number < 2) {
        return list;
    }

    if (number == 2) {
        list.add(2L);
        return list;
    }

    for (long i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        while (number % i == 0) {
            number /= i;
            list.add(i);
            return facrec2(list, number);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

method works for max values (after changing signature to Integer, works for Integer max value too). Logic of both suppose to be the same, only recursive implementation of the second makes the difference...

Comment: +1. I think you could have done a better job debugging (or at least demonstrating your debugging), but it's surprisingly subtle how this bug leads to this exception.

Comment: Yes, but I got both function from someone else, just as an example, and impatiently posted on stackoverflow, instead of get myself to work:)

Comment: `Logic of [iterative and recursive handling of any given trial divisor supposed] to be the same` - with recursion, you _never_ get to increment (and re-check) `i` after discovering `i` divides what's left of `number`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
```

The problem is here. If `number == Integer.MAX_VALUE` this loop will never terminate. Once `i` gets to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the next increment sets it to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which is very negative, and the loop continues to execute, so you will keep adding to the list forever and run out of memory.

The simplest solution is to change the loop condition to `<` and handle the case where `number` still has its original value separately (i.e. the case where `number` is prime). You can also exit the loop once `number == 1`.

Comment: +1. Note that when `i` gets to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `number` gets set to `1`; but since `i` gets set to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` immediately afterward, it still stays less than `number`. And then `i` eventually reaches `1`, at which point `number % i == 0` is permanently true, so the list gets filled with arbitrarily many `1`'s until you run out of memory. It's just bad luck that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` happens to be prime. :-)

Comment: Yes, exactly this happen. first function when changed while to if yields [2147483647, -1], but gives wrong answers, for 120, for example, returns 2, 3, 4, 5 (4 is not a prime). So while is important, and function needs fix which you proposed. The second seems be fine.

Comment: The `while/if` change that was proposed, not by me, now deleted, is not correct. You need the `while` to get prime factors.

Comment: You can speed it up consideraby by testing `i*i < number`, again being careful about wraparound.

Answer (score 0):

This loop never terminates. When counter i reaches Integer.MAX_VALUE it rolls over. You should not allow equality in the loop condition.